# Performance issues with LINQ query when including OR clause

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following LINQ to Entities query slows down substantially when the commented line below is included in the query.  Is there a better way to phrase this?

The 'OR' clause should only take into account the following lines:

```
((o.Type_ID == (int) RecordEnums.RecordType.Lead) && (o.Item_ID == l1.Lead_ID)) 
|| ((o.Type_ID == (int)RecordEnums.RecordType.Opportunity)(o.Item_ID == o1.Opportunity_ID))
```

### Full Query

```
return withItemsPending
                       ? (from l1 in db.Leads
                          from o1 in db.Opportunities.Where(x => (x.Lead_ID == l1.Lead_ID) && (x.Company_ID == companyId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          from l2
                              in
                              db.Tasks.Where(
                                  o =>
                                  ((o.IsCompleted ?? false) == false) &&
                                  (o.TaskType_ID == typeId) &&
                                  ((o.Type_ID == (int) RecordEnums.RecordType.Lead) && (o.Item_ID == l1.Lead_ID)) 
                                  //|| ((o.Type_ID == (int)RecordEnums.RecordType.Opportunity) && (o.Item_ID == o1.Opportunity_ID)) 
                                  &&
                                  (o.Due_Date > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -1)))


                          where (l1.Company_ID == companyId)
                          select l1)


                       : (from l1 in db.Leads where (0 == 1) select l1);
        }
```

### Here's the offending query:

```
SELECT     Extent1.Lead_ID
FROM         Leads AS Extent1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Opportunities AS Extent2 ON Extent2.Lead_ID = Extent1.Lead_ID AND Extent2.Company_ID = 118 INNER JOIN
                      Tasks AS Extent3 ON 0 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[IsCompleted] IS NULL) THEN CAST(0 AS bit) ELSE [Extent3].[IsCompleted] END) AND Extent3.TaskType_ID = 1 AND 
                      5 = Extent3.Type_ID AND Extent3.Item_ID = Extent1.Lead_ID OR
                      4 = Extent3.Type_ID AND Extent3.Item_ID = Extent2.Opportunity_ID AND Extent3.Due_Date > DATEADD(day, - 1, SysDateTime())
WHERE     (Extent1.Company_ID = 118)
```

Comment: Check it in IntelliTrace and get sql query then debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the offending query. Any ideas on what I can do to improve it?

Comment: Could this be the case of simply the query returning considerably more data? Did you try commenting out the other leg of the `OR` (the one with `RecordType.Lead`) to see if the performance issues remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is "give me the items that are not completed AND are due later than yesterday AND are EITHER Lead OR Opportunity", you need to add extra brackets around the 2 statements you want to OR.  What you are currently saying is "give me the items that are either not completed AND Lead OR Opportunity AND due later than yesterday".

The code will then be like this:

```
return withItemsPending
                       ? (from l1 in db.Leads
                          from o1 in db.Opportunities.Where(x => (x.Lead_ID == l1.Lead_ID) && (x.Company_ID == companyId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          from l2
                              in
                              db.Tasks.Where(
                                  o =>
                                  ((o.IsCompleted ?? false) == false) &&
                                  (o.TaskType_ID == typeId) &&
                                  (((o.Type_ID == (int) RecordEnums.RecordType.Lead) && (o.Item_ID == l1.Lead_ID)) 
                                  || ((o.Type_ID == (int)RecordEnums.RecordType.Opportunity) && (o.Item_ID == o1.Opportunity_ID)))
                                  &&
                                  (o.Due_Date > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -1)))


                          where (l1.Company_ID == companyId)
                          select l1)


                       : (from l1 in db.Leads where (0 == 1) select l1);
        }
```